# Couchbase -> PouchDB deleted document issue

Tags: couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have this setup: Couchbase -> Sync Gateway -> PouchDB.

I had a document in couchbase bucket which was deleted (manual delete from bucket) at a later point of time,

Problem is when the sync happens on a new client., I get with other documents that specific deleted document also (Can see doc id and other data). 
Strange thing is I cannot find that doc anywhere in couchbase buckets neither in _sync bucket.

I also used cbft(Couchbase Full Text Search)., the max it gives is the _sync information of that document.

Could it be possible that it exists in rev cache and trying to replicate?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, in general, you should avoid manipulating documents in Couchbase Server if you're using it with Sync Gateway.  The reason is Sync Gateway (and Couchbase Lite) need extra meta-data to syncing, versioning, and conflict resolution.

If you set up bucket shadowing (which is deprecated), there is a "shadow bucket" that works along with a normal bucket to allow accessing a db through CB Server and Sync Gateway.  It sounds like your doc is still in the shadow bucket.

Best practice is to run everything through Sync Gateway, and not manipulate documents directly on CB Server (meaning treat CB Server as a read-only source).

Comment: Thanks for the input @Hod.  Yes it I'm using Sync Gateway., and will note down to avoid making manual changes.